# Determine if node is Leaf node or not in Gremlin

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune, tinkerpop3

I am looking for a ways to find out the all the nodes coming out of a `root node` are either `leaf node` or `intermediate node`.

I have added the a sample graph.

```
g.addV('company').property(id,'TESTNX01').property('name','Alphabet').next()
g.addV('company').property(id,'TESTNX02').property('name','Google').next()
g.addV('company').property(id,'TESTNX03').property('name','Youtube').next()
g.addV('company').property(id,'TESTNX05').property('name','YoutubeKids').next()
g.addV('person').property(id,'TESTNX01_1900-01-01_1_1').property('bu_id', 'TESTNX01_1900-01-01_1_1').property('name', 'W Karl David Laxton').next()
g.addV('person').property(id,'TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_1').property('bu_id', 'TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_1').property('name', 'Steven H Strong').next()
g.addV('person').property(id,'TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_2').property('bu_id', 'TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_2').property('name', 'Adrian Matthew Paul Rowe').next()
g.addV('person').property(id,'TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_3').property('bu_id', 'TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_3').property('name', 'Steven Henry Strong').next()
g.addV('person').property(id,'TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_4').property('bu_id', 'TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_4').property('name', 'Dom Robinson').next()
g.addV('person').property(id,'TESTNX03_1900-01-01_1_3').property('bu_id', 'TESTNX03_1900-01-01_1_3').property('name', 'Dominic Nesbitt Robinson').next()
g.addV('person').property(id,'TESTNX03_1900-01-01_1_4').property('bu_id', 'TESTNX03_1900-01-01_1_4').property('name', 'Adrian Matthew Paul Rowe').next()
g.addV('person').property(id,'TESTNX03_1900-01-01_1_5').property('bu_id', 'TESTNX03_1900-01-01_1_5').property('name', 'William Laxton').next()
g.addV('person').property(id,'TESTNX03_1900-01-01_1_6').property('bu_id', 'TESTNX03_1900-01-01_1_6').property('name', 'Will Laxton').next()


g.addE('HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO').from(__.V('TESTNX01')).to(__.V('TESTNX01_1900-01-01_1_1')).property(id,'TESTNX01_HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO_TESTNX01_1900-01-01_1_1').property('perc_value', 25).next()
g.addE('HAS_VOTING_PC_TO').from(__.V('TESTNX01')).to(__.V('TESTNX01_1900-01-01_1_1')).property(id,'TESTNX01_HAS_VOTING_PC_TO_TESTNX01_1900-01-01_1_1').property('perc_value', 50).next()
g.addE('HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO').from(__.V('TESTNX01')).to(__.V('TESTNX02')).property(id,'TESTNX01_HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO_TESTNX02').property('perc_value', 75).next()
g.addE('HAS_VOTING_PC_TO').from(__.V('TESTNX01')).to(__.V('TESTNX02')).property(id,'TESTNX01_HAS_VOTING_PC_TO_TESTNX02').property('perc_value', 50).next()
g.addE('HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO').from(__.V('TESTNX02')).to(__.V('TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_1')).property(id,'TESTNX02_HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO_TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_1').property('perc_value', 25).next()
g.addE('HAS_VOTING_PC_TO').from(__.V('TESTNX02')).to(__.V('TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_1')).property(id,'TESTNX02_HAS_VOTING_PC_TO_TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_1').property('perc_value', 25).next()
g.addE('HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO').from(__.V('TESTNX02')).to(__.V('TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_2')).property(id,'TESTNX02_HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO_TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_2').property('perc_value', 25).next()
g.addE('HAS_VOTING_PC_TO').from(__.V('TESTNX02')).to(__.V('TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_2')).property(id,'TESTNX02_HAS_VOTING_PC_TO_TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_2').property('perc_value', 25).next()
g.addE('HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO').from(__.V('TESTNX02')).to(__.V('TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_3')).property(id,'TESTNX02_HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO_TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_3').property('perc_value', 10).next()
g.addE('HAS_VOTING_PC_TO').from(__.V('TESTNX02')).to(__.V('TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_3')).property(id,'TESTNX02_HAS_VOTING_PC_TO_TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_3').property('perc_value', 5).next()
g.addE('HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO').from(__.V('TESTNX02')).to(__.V('TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_4')).property(id,'TESTNX02_HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO_TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_4').property('perc_value', 10).next()
g.addE('HAS_VOTING_PC_TO').from(__.V('TESTNX02')).to(__.V('TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_4')).property(id,'TESTNX02_HAS_VOTING_PC_TO_TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_4').property('perc_value', 5).next()
g.addE('HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO').from(__.V('TESTNX02')).to(__.V('TESTNX03')).property(id,'TESTNX02_HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO_TESTNX03').property('perc_value', 30).next()
g.addE('HAS_VOTING_PC_TO').from(__.V('TESTNX02')).to(__.V('TESTNX03')).property(id,'TESTNX02_HAS_VOTING_PC_TO_TESTNX03').property('perc_value', 50).next()
g.addE('HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO').from(__.V('TESTNX03')).to(__.V('TESTNX03_1900-01-01_1_3')).property(id,'TESTNX03_HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO_TESTNX03_1900-01-01_1_3').property('perc_value', 20).next()
g.addE('HAS_VOTING_PC_TO').from(__.V('TESTNX03')).to(__.V('TESTNX03_1900-01-01_1_3')).property(id,'TESTNX03_HAS_VOTING_PC_TO_TESTNX03_1900-01-01_1_3').property('perc_value', 15).next()
g.addE('HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO').from(__.V('TESTNX03')).to(__.V('TESTNX03_1900-01-01_1_4')).property(id,'TESTNX03_HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO_TESTNX03_1900-01-01_1_4').property('perc_value', 20).next()
g.addE('HAS_VOTING_PC_TO').from(__.V('TESTNX03')).to(__.V('TESTNX03_1900-01-01_1_4')).property(id,'TESTNX03_HAS_VOTING_PC_TO_TESTNX03_1900-01-01_1_4').property('perc_value', 25).next()
g.addE('HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO').from(__.V('TESTNX03')).to(__.V('TESTNX03_1900-01-01_1_5')).property(id,'TESTNX03_HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO_TESTNX03_1900-01-01_1_5').property('perc_value', 10).next()
g.addE('HAS_VOTING_PC_TO').from(__.V('TESTNX03')).to(__.V('TESTNX03_1900-01-01_1_5')).property(id,'TESTNX03_HAS_VOTING_PC_TO_TESTNX03_1900-01-01_1_5').property('perc_value', 5).next()
g.addE('HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO').from(__.V('TESTNX03')).to(__.V('TESTNX03_1900-01-01_1_6')).property(id,'TESTNX03_HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO_TESTNX03_1900-01-01_1_6').property('perc_value', 20).next()
g.addE('HAS_VOTING_PC_TO').from(__.V('TESTNX03')).to(__.V('TESTNX03_1900-01-01_1_6')).property(id,'TESTNX03_HAS_VOTING_PC_TO_TESTNX03_1900-01-01_1_6').property('perc_value', 10).next()
g.addE('HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO').from(__.V('TESTNX03')).to(__.V('TESTNX05')).property(id,'TESTNX03_HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO_TESTNX05').property('perc_value', 20).next()
g.addE('HAS_VOTING_PC_TO').from(__.V('TESTNX03')).to(__.V('TESTNX05')).property(id,'TESTNX03_HAS_VOTING_PC_TO_TESTNX05').property('perc_value', 20).next()
```

I am trying to get the all possible `nodes` of the `root node` and see if they are `leaf` or not. The 'leaf' `nodes` are assigned value `Y`, while the intermediate `nodes` get `N`.

Sample output:

```
{'root_company' : 'TESTNX01', 'Shareholder': 'TESTNX03', 'leaf': 'N'}
{'root_company' : 'TESTNX01', 'Shareholder': 'TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_1', 'leaf': 'Y'}
.
.
.
{'root_company' : 'TESTNX01', 'Shareholder': 'TESTNX05', 'leaf': 'Y'}
```

Any leads would be deeply appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to test for edges on each vertex and return "Y" or "N". Most simply this can be done with `choose()`:

```
gremlin> g.V('TESTNX01').out().choose(outE(),constant('N'),constant('Y'))
==>N
==>Y
==>Y
==>N
```

More specific to your request for traversing the entire tree, you might do something like:

```
gremlin> g.V('TESTNX01').repeat(out()).emit().dedup().project('v','leaf').by(valueMap()).by(choose(outE(),constant('N'),constant('Y')))
==>[v:[name:[Google]],leaf:N]
==>[v:[name:[W Karl David Laxton],bu_id:[TESTNX01_1900-01-01_1_1]],leaf:Y]
==>[v:[name:[Dom Robinson],bu_id:[TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_4]],leaf:Y]
==>[v:[name:[Steven Henry Strong],bu_id:[TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_3]],leaf:Y]
==>[v:[name:[Adrian Matthew Paul Rowe],bu_id:[TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_2]],leaf:Y]
==>[v:[name:[Steven H Strong],bu_id:[TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_1]],leaf:Y]
==>[v:[name:[Youtube]],leaf:N]
==>[v:[name:[Adrian Matthew Paul Rowe],bu_id:[TESTNX03_1900-01-01_1_4]],leaf:Y]
==>[v:[name:[William Laxton],bu_id:[TESTNX03_1900-01-01_1_5]],leaf:Y]
==>[v:[name:[Dominic Nesbitt Robinson],bu_id:[TESTNX03_1900-01-01_1_3]],leaf:Y]
==>[v:[name:[YoutubeKids]],leaf:Y]
==>[v:[name:[Will Laxton],bu_id:[TESTNX03_1900-01-01_1_6]],leaf:Y]
```

Comment: Thank you @stephen for the quick reply.  Lets say I want to retrieve the same output for multiple inputs in `g.V('xyz', 'abc')` and do a `groupBy` . How would the query look

Comment: i dont think anything changes for multiple inputs. and i'm not clear on what you intend to `group()` on

Comment: The idea behind adding `group()` is to segregate data based on the `root node`. For eg. I have added `root: 'abc/xyz'` in the below data.

```
[root: 'abc',v:[name:[Dom Robinson],bu_id:[TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_4]],leaf:Y]
[root: 'abc',v:[name:[Steven Henry Strong],bu_id:[TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_3]],leaf:Y]
[root: 'xyz',v:[name:[Adrian Matthew Paul Rowe],bu_id:[TESTNX02_1900-01-01_1_2]],leaf:Y]
```

Comment: do you mean that you just want to have the list of vertices with whether they are a leaf or not for each input vertex (i.e. root)?

Comment: Hello @stepehen, yes, I meant that and I am able to achieve that result now. Thank you for following it up.